# Driving stepper motors adafruit motor shield v2

Tags: arduino-uno, power, hardware, arduino-motor-shield

I got an Arduino Uno Rev3 and Adafruits Motor Shield V2. I also got two RepRap stepper motors:

```
Frame size 42 x 42mm - NEMA 17
1.8 degree step angle
Length 47mm
Holding torque 44 N.cm (4.4kg.cm, 62oz.in)
Voltage 2.8V
Current/Phase 1.68A
Resistance/Phase 1.65ohm
Inductance/Phase 2.8mH
Inertia 68g.cm
Bipolar, 4-wire
```

I thought I was going to be able to run the steppers with the motor shield, but when I tried run one of the steppers it jumps (runs little bit, then stops, then runs etc) until it reach  x steps. I'm driving the the motor shield with 12v 3A power supply.

I read somewhere that the Adafruit steppers should be at-least 5V. Is that correct? Do I need to buy new steppers or any suggestions of stepper driver (shield)?

How many amps do I need to run both steppers at the same time? 1.68 x 2 = 3.36A?

I'm building two of these: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C15yPENQ074

Any suggestions/help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Adafruit's page says "MOST 1.5-3V MOTORS WILL NOT WORK". https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-motor-shield-v2-for-arduino/powering-motors

Comment: Yeah, I did see that... So I need new motors or another shield/controller. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: That shield is a motor shield; not a stepper shield. You can use it to drive some steppers, but it's not ideal. Regular stepper drivers provide current limiting, micro-stepping etc. PS. by putting 12V on a 2.8v stepper, you can burn out the stepper.